# How to overlay the border of the element whose "border and overflow hidden" are set with a child element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I wrote such a code, but the border of the child element specifying `position: absolute` did not overlap the border of the parent element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lists {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 15px solid green;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;  /* .items border width */
}

.items+.items {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.items {
  float: left;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 15px solid black;  /* overlap this border! */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="items">text</li>
    <li class="items">text</li>
    <li class="items">text</li>
    <li class="items">text</li>
    <li class="items">text</li>
    <li class="items">text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[According to W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#valdef-overflow-hidden), overflow hidden thought that there is a possibility of hiding the border.

> This value indicates that the box’s content is clipped to its padding
>   box and that the UA must not provide any scrolling user interface to
>   view the content outside the clipping region, nor allow scrolling by
>   direct intervention of the user, such as dragging on a touch screen or
>   using the scrolling wheel on a mouse.

Actually, when I removed overflow, I got the ideal behaviour.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lists {
  position: relative;
  /* this property removed overflow: hidden; */
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 15px solid green;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;  /* .items border width */
}

.items+.items {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.items {
  float: left;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 15px solid black;  /* overlap this border! */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="items">text</li>
    <li class="items">text</li>
    <li class="items">text</li>
    <li class="items">text</li>
    <li class="items">text</li>
    <li class="items">text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, I want to set overflow: hidden. Is this problem caused by the overflow property? How can solve this problem?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: as you can see, it's about padding box thus the border of the parent will get visibile since you will hide the -15px from the top ... what you want to achieve?

Comment: Considering the case where the number of characters of the child element increases so that it extends beyond the parent element, the parent element is set to `overflow: hidden`. Therefore, we want to overlay the black border of the child element on the green border of the parent element, keeping this `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/04wzq396/2/

The problem is that if you use `position` and `overflow` properties for the same element you can only pop the child outside of its borders with `position: fixed;` (relative to the viewport). `position: absolute;` works in a similar way, but it places the element relative to its first positioned ancestor.

So a solution here is to add a container for the overflown element and move the position property there. If you then increase the `top` property of the `.list` element from -15 to 0, the green border is no longer visible.